# Set Camera Rotation in Libgdx

Tags: java, camera, rotation, box2d, libgdx

I can't seem to find a way to tie the rotation of my ortho camera in libgdx (project with box2d) to the rotation of a box2d body.
There is the method of cam.rotate(xy), giving it an impulse or acceleration, but I would like to set a definitive value, something like

```
cam.setAngle(player.body.getAngle());
```

How would I go about doing this? Do I have to write my own function? If so, then how? I want the rotation of the camera to always be the same as the player's...

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a good nights sleep I just woke up with the solution in mind!
the function cam.angle(angle) obviously does set the angle to what you want (in degrees) - but you must only do it once and not in your update-loop, otherwise the camera just starts spinning. Which is obvious, but I just didn't get it.

the other problem is that the box2d body has "endless" degrees (i convert everything to degrees with *MathUtils.radiansToDegrees), so I had to constrain these to 0 to 359:

```
playerAngle = player.body.getAngle()*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;

while(playerAngle<=0){
        playerAngle += 360;
    }
while(playerAngle>360){
        playerAngle -= 360;
    }
```

The camera's degrees go from -180 to 180, so you must also convert these to 0 to 359:

```
    camAngle = -getCameraCurrentXYAngle(camera) + 180;
```

The function "getCameraCurrentXYAngle(cam) is the following:

```
public float getCameraCurrentXYAngle(OrthographicCamera cam)
{
    return (float)Math.atan2(cam.up.x, cam.up.y)*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
}
```

And now in use this to update your cam to the rotation of your player:

```
    camera.rotate((camAngle-playerAngle)+180);
```

I hope this helps the person who upvoted my question;)

Cheers and have a productive day!
Jonas

Answer (score 2):

In Box2D, angles can be infinite as stated in the answer suggested. The method used to bound the angle however is quite inefficient. A more efficient solution would instead use modular arithmetic through the following snippet:

```
playerAngle = (player.body.getAngle() % 360) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees()
```

Working out the camera's angle would be the next step, the solution provided above is adequate in this regard but could be condensed further into:

```
public float getCameraAngle(OrthographicCamera cam) {
    return ((float) -Math.atan2(cam.up.x, cam.up.y) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees) + 180;
}
```

Now rotating the camera by the given angle is efficient for all values possible using the `rotate()` method:

```
camera.rotate((getCameraAngle(camera) - playerAngle) + 180)
```